# C++: how to define class instance in structure. Class has parametrized constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have class C1:

```
class C1 : public Print {
public:
  C1(int p1, int p2, int p3);
};
```

I need to define an instance of this class inside structure S1:

```
struct S1{
   C1 c1;
};
```

But the compiler says:

note: 'S1::S1()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:...

error: no matching function for call to 'C1::C1() ...

candidate: C1::C1(int, int, int) note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided

candidate: constexpr C1::C1(const C1&) class C1 : public Print { candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

When I compile this code:

```
Struct S1{
   C1 c1(1,1,1);
};
```

the compiler says:

error: expected identifier before numeric constant C1 c1(1,1,1);

error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant

I don't need to call the constructor of C1 class, i will call it later. I can not just delete this constructor in C1 code because it is a library.

It's OK when i define global variable: 
`C1 c1(1,1,1);`

Comment: You can write `struct S1{ C1 c1 = C1(1,1,1); };` or `struct S1{ C1 c1{1,1,1}; };`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the compiler complains due to ambiguity between `C1 c1(1, 1, 1)` variable and declaration of function `c1` returning `C1` (in general, it has no way to tell what you've wanted in general). To avoid that, either use brace-init `C1 c1{1, 1, 1}` or `=`: `C1 c1 = C1(1, 1, 1)`.

If you don't want to initialize it to `C1(1, 1, 1)` you can take the parameters in `S1` constructor and pass them in init-list:

```
struct S1{
  S1(int p1, int p2, int p3): c1(p1, p2, p3) {};
  C1 c1;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create an S1 object, C1 object is constructed using it only non-default constructor (c'tor).

In order for that to work, you shall do one of the following:

1. Define a [default c'tor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) for C1, OR
2. Define a c'tor for S1, and call C1's c'tor in S1 c'tor's [init list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Answer (score 1):

> I don't need to call the constructor of C1 class, i will call it later. I can not just delete this constructor in C1 code because it is a library.

Deferred initialization of a data member with no meaningful default constructor available is best achieve with `std::optional`;

```
#include <optional>

struct S1{
   std::optional<C1> c1;
};
```

This allows you to first construct `S1` instances and then construct their `c1` data members later on.

```
S1 s;

// ... do stuff with s ...

s.c1 = C1(1, 2, 3);
```

If you can't use C++17, consider a third-party `optional` implementation. Otherwise, go with a (smart) pointer.